# How to intergarte react native front end with django backend

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

[Post Method Used In ReactNative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFzxd.png)

Error raised
`Forbidden: /api/login/`

I created a user API using djangorest framework and it is functioning well, however i dont know how to add it to my react native front end for authentication. I would like users to login and the drf to authenticate them. Is there a tutorial i can follow, i tried to look at a few but they didnt work for me. I'm new to react native. Would appreciate elaborate answers and shared resources

Currently using expo cli and unable to fetch data from drf(django rest framework).

is there a way i can request my post method to use djangosessions for authentication instead of auth tokens

the method in the image only works if
`'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',`
is disabled and this is used to get data in api so it cannot be excluded

Answer (score 1):

welcome to ReactNative
You can use different libraries to handle an api request.
Take a look at axios:
https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: thank you for your response...i tried to post data without axios however, the post method only works if  'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', is disabled in settings...but this is neccessary for me to get my data..is there a way i can specify the authentication method in the post requests headers?

Comment: @Zainy_m does your api need token? if yes you should put it in your header request > {Authorization: `${'Bearer ' + token}`}